# Iptables rule to drop packets to and from local network

Tags: iptables, virtualbox, firewall, virtual-machine

I want to set a virtual machine on laptop, but I don't trust the guest system fully, so I would like to block it's access to local network (to network 192.168.0.1/16 or 10.0.0.1/8 or *... the other one that i don't remember at the moment*). To achieve this I wanted to set iptables to drop all packets to and from LAN, but I don't now much and nowhere on the internet I was able to find a tutorial. I only found how to block access to Internet and leave access to LAN, but changing the lines in any way that I can think of wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution may be to just disconnect the guest's NIC in Virtualbox's networking settings until you're ready to bring it online.

If you still want to use `iptables` then on the guest run:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

This changes the default policy for the chains to DROP.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to block access to LAN (local area network) only, NOT to the Internet. I will edit my question in a moment to be more specific.